# Regex problem - Multiple matches of groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I have different texts. The order and the occurences of the matches differs:

```
This is a text: <<<String(10)>>>\nToday is the: <<<Date(10)>>>
```

or

```
<<<String(10)>>> This was a text: \nToday is the: <<<Date(10)>>>
```

or

```
<<<String(10)>>><<<Date(10)>>> This was a text and a date...
```

Now I search for a regex which give me an array of the matches. 1st example should give me:

```
['This is a text: ', '<<<String(10)>>>', '\nToday is the: ', '<<<Date(10)>>>']
```

I tried something like this:

```
/(.*?)(\<{3}.*?\>{3})/
```

This works for the order of the first example but not for different orders. Please give me a hint!

Comment: Try `s.split(/(<<<.*?>>>)/)`

Comment: It works! Specifiying a seperator by regex will result in entries with '<<<' & '>>>'. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
s.split(/(<{3}.*?>{3})/)
```

would do the work but it'll give one empty entry. If you want to remove it, you can use:

```
s.split(/(<{3}.*?>{3})/).filter(str => str.length > 0)
```

```js
var s = "This is a text: <<<String(10)>>>\nToday is the: <<<Date(10)>>>";
var arr = s.split(/(<{3}.*?>{3})/).filter(str => str.length > 0);
console.log(arr)
```